# My Content Security Policy blocks more than I expect

Tags: content-security-policy

I've created an Azure Service Application. I'm using a site content security policy to secure it. Except when i use it, it blocks things I do not expect it to block.

I am using recaptcha, which is why i need to add google.

My CSP:

```
default-src 'self'; 
script-src: 'self' https://google.com [my website url]; 
script-src-elem: 'self' https://google.com [my website url];
```

Frustratingly I'm still receiving the following messages:

```
The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LfWwj4lAAAAAFJ-LTZkzZJNAuQxkiPNMrlD93ai ("script-src-elem").

The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at [my website url]/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js ("script-src-elem")
```

I would expect that the line '**script-src-elem**' entry would take care of these errors.

It seems CSP is less straightforward as I thought. Anybody have a clue what to do here?

UPDATE: it's a firefox issue :'(

Answer (score 0):

The captcha script source is being loaded from [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), not google.com. These are not the same sources and you will need to add [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

It is not straightforward to understand why bootstrap is not loading, as likely both 'self' and your explicit page address should allow it. The most likely explanation is another default CSP added by your framework or web server, check your response headers for another restrictive CSP.